# How does a moving magnetic field cause motion in the Al strip rotor?

Tags: motor, electromagnetism, brushless-dc-motor, induction-motor, electromagnetic

Consider the following information:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7snjbmdYlDI

How would you explain how the moving magnetic field causes motion in AL labeled rotor?

Comment: Did you try turning on your audio? Or just Googling the term given in the Description.

Comment: We don't have time to watch the video. Edit your question and explain the plot and what AL stands for. (_Al_ is aluminium / aluminum, if that's what you mean. Capitals matter.)

Comment: @Asmyldof - Yes, I did both things.  My question is about seeking other people's thoughts.

Comment: @transistor 5 - there is no plot per se.  The video author is showing/explaining a discovery he made regarding magnetic induction.  AL=aluminium--what else would it mean?

Comment: "AL" stands for [lots of things](http://www.abbreviations.com/AL) - Alabama, for example. All the elements of the [periodic table](http://www.ptable.com/) only have the first letter capitalised. "AL" looks like an acronym whereas "Al" is an abbreviation / chemical symbol.

Comment: @transistor - Interestingly enough it stands for the 2nd item on the list that you linked and it would have nothing to do with the first item on the list as that item makes no sense with respect to the context within which I used the abbreviation AL.  To simplify, I'm really wanting to know how a moving magnetic field on one rotor causes unconnected Al segments/strips on a 2nd rotor to cause the 2nd rotor to rotate (i.e what is actually happening within the Al to cause the rotor to turn)?

Comment: Thanks for putting up with me. I gave in and watched the video. It reminds me of the [mechanical electricity meters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_meter#Electromechanical_meters). Is it the same effect?

Comment: I'm not certain--but it looks like it may be the same effect.  Based on wiki info, it appears the effect is some kind of electrostatic induction in which the moving magnets create eddy currents (i.e. "loops of electrical current induced within conductors by a changing magnetic field in the conductor, due to Faraday's law of induction. Eddy currents flow in closed loops within conductors, in planes perpendicular to the magnetic field."

Comment: According to Lenz's law, an eddy current creates a magnetic field that opposes the magnetic field that created it & causes a reverse force on the source magnetic field. But how is the current created in the 1st place?  Doesn't one need a charged particle in an electric field for such a force to exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving magnets create eddy currents in the aluminum by electromagnetic induction as explained by [Faraday's law of induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction). [Lenz's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law) essentially states an effect of Faraday's law.

The demonstration essentially shows an eddy-current clutch or coupling that is similar to an [eddy-current brake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current_brake). The same principle is used in a mechanical speedometer. Variable-speed drives based on this principle have been manufactured for about 80 years. [Here is an explanation](http://www.dynamatic.com/technology/how-it-works.html) by a successor to the company that was the original manufacturer of eddy-current drives.

Although there are similarities between this and a rotating disc watt-hour meter, the meter is more like an induction motor. Here, a magnetic field is rotated by a motor. In an induction motor or a watt-hour meter, AC currents create a rotating magnetic field.

Comment: Good explanation & references. How does a moving magnetic field/flux cause an Eddy current to form in the Al?  What actually happens on an atomic level?

Comment: For what actually happens on an atomic level, I believe that you must look into Maxwell's equations, quantum electrodynamics and atomic physics.